# User gets randomly logged out, strange url shown, user can't login until cache cleared or reboots

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Examples of the strange URL(s) that we get when this occurs: (note the long string before the /controller/ part)

```
http://domain.com/(F(RJ98SBleKwJwzM59cfA_Kr5pxNDeLW07xV65XfHzSqeZlZcgvl1TwHeH_s4rlWWPRo3dV9KGDati6kVlQ3o--KnVANIpqwvOB_H8cBO7MhPLXO2MIHITYUKnLp3DzKPwiQUOwaHa8fQpuXsbz1NIiuRICY4CaEBYhQ1qwkX64plaqhCGk6CG7Gk7WFB_Njq-XTtGDXLvcenSBZvMJ22Fgw2))/controller1/action1

http://domain.com/(F(ZbnIOH70BxAn2Eo6zzdH9zVWu4Oa7DrMaRk_tF41F3WcRapNeXghfDY0_f-2uYbPkWv1UV1ZyPp3tBPSM0I-UDbIyU2O_MKWPVcSg4D3uRo5kA6kRu7niobbJuPL5F8Gkc2g_a6mVhp_JGIRR4i1SRhyh8ovneMFzXHCGWU75TJogqlkjj5XTZNhG_LgqXHOy51Z92ueXjpLQdGh7b4kg_iixNPEn8qJHm_fudm-R8U1))/controller2/action2
```

I'm actually having trouble reproducing it since there doesn't seem to be a clear pattern on how it occurs.  It occurs randomly for different controllers/actions and these actions can/may have different authorization attributes (we're authorizing based on Roles with ASP.NET Membership).  I'm starting to think it's client-related, though, as when the user reports the issue, I'm able to log onto that same account and access those pages without an issue.

Symptoms:

1. once logged out, user can't log back in
2. strange url shown when attempting to log back in

Things that seem to fix it (from the user):

1. clearing browser cache AND restarting Safari
2. rebooting

Does anyone have a lead as to why that strange URL is being generated? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That URL contains [cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx). Is the users' browser possibly disabling cookies and then not re-enabling them until restarting the browser?

Comment: Can you provide the code from logout mechanizm?

Comment: just as an added note, please don't use cookie-less (if there ever was any intention and not just a config issue)  there are numerous security reasons why its bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the cookieless feature in .net. So it's the forms authentication in the URL. Have a look at this question:

[IIS7.5 ASP.NET MVC users hitting strange URLs: /(F(1xe9eXIxPz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229565/iis7-5-asp-net-mvc-users-hitting-strange-urls-f1xe9exixpz)

Comment: Thanks, I think I can figure it out from here.