# MVC ignores route prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-routing

One of our MVC sites has some odd URLs showing up in google analytics:

www.domain.com/(F([long 232 character hex string here]))/Route/etc

There's a very long string inserted before the main route which the MVC routing ignores.

What is this?

I know this site runs MVC and the same thing happens:
https://stackoverflow.com/(F())/users/login

Comment: I have encountered it when running the site from tablets, my guess was that the iPad saved the cookies that way, been wondering too, will wait for an answer :)

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229565/iis7-5-asp-net-mvc-users-hitting-strange-urls-f1xe9exixpz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:
According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx
the "(F([long 232 character hex string here]))" is the Forms Authentication ticket for a cookieless request.