# Cookieless sessions in MVC cause shared session between seperate tabs in the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session-cookies

I am trying to avoid the problem whereby users of the site I am working on can open a new browser tab and end up sharing the same session.

I tried to use cookieless sesisons, but consensus is that cookieless sessions are not supported in MVC, but do work under certain conditions

***Definitive not supported answer here:***
[ASP.NET MVC and using cookieless sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638446/asp-net-mvc-and-using-cookieless-sessions)

***This seems like a hack, especially as you cant use POST:***
[MVC2 Cookieless Session Issue using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972433/mvc2-cookieless-session-issue-using-post)

So how do you prevent multiple tabs being seen as the same session on the server please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

browser tabs share the same session id because the id comes from the browser. HTML5 SessionStorage, window.sessionStorage, addresses this limitation.  That might not be viable depending on the backwards compatibility you need.

This goes into much more depth.
[How to differ sessions in browser-tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs)

Comment: Thanks. Solved it using a Guid() passed to the view in the model so the server can match posted data to the relevant tab

Comment: @SkeetJon - Hi, I am facing same issue in MVC. please can you post answer with some sample code . How you solve this issue using Guid() in MVC ... Thanks in advance

Comment: add the guid as a property of the model, then when posted back the server knows which session it pertains to